# How do I open PDF files in kword?

Tags: pdf, conversion

I have read in many places that kword can open pdf and save it in doc format ! but on ubuntu 11.10 I can not open pdf using kword as it does not showing pdf as supported files ?!!!

I want a pdf to doc converter on Ubuntu 11.10. I can open pdf using libreofffice but it displaying garbled characters with over 1000+ pages for a pdf with only 15 pages.

What can I do so that Kword became able to open pdf and save it to doc or odt format ??

Answer (score 5):

Install the package `libreoffice-pdfimport`:

[image: Install via the software center]

Or by using the command `sudo apt-get install libreoffice-pdfimport` and Writer will be able to open your PDF's correctly, then you can save them in ODT or DOC.

Comment: I already have that package installed. Read my query again.

Comment: If you insist on importing PDF directly into Kword, install the tarball here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/kpdfimport/

Comment: You may be able to simply do File>Import in Kword...see: http://embraceubuntu.com/2007/04/10/convertimport-from-pdf-and-keep-the-formatting/

Comment: Tarball does not work. It giving lots of erroes. It might be due to my lack of  knowledge or there is a bug in the souce itself.

Comment: @CuriousApprentice what errors does it give you? Missing dependencies per chance?

Answer (score 1):

Abiword works for me:

In a terminal type

```
sudo apt-get install abiword
```

To run it from the terminal type `abiword` .

In abiword (on the system panel - located at the top-left corner of your desktop) click **File** and select **Open'* and locate the pdf. Make changes to your file and click on **File** again, select **Save as...** Type filename to save with and select **microsoft (.doc)** from below in **save file as type** and click **save**.

After finishing with the aforesaid, locate your file in doc format and open it with your doc app - like openoffice or libreoffice.

Answer (score 0):

You don't to install Kword - on the command line you can use this command to extract text from PDF:

```
pdftotext
```

NAME
       pdftotext - Portable Document Format (PDF) to text converter (version 3.00)

SYNOPSIS
       pdftotext [options] [PDF-file [text-file]]

DESCRIPTION
       Pdftotext converts Portable Document Format (PDF) files to plain text.

```
   Pdftotext  reads  the  PDF  file, PDF-file, and writes a text file, text-file.  If text-file is not specified, pdftotext converts file.pdf to file.txt.  If
   text-file is ´-', the text is sent to stdout.
```

Comment: I don't think the author wants an output in plain text, but rather a ODT or DOC word processing document that would retain all the formatting as seen in the original PDF.

Comment: @user30275: I do need to preserve the formating. Why installing pdf2text. If i need something like that then I can Simply use "Okular."

Comment: pdftotext is part of the default install of Ubuntu, you don't have to install it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Ok This is for all those who neither can open pdf using Kword nor using LibreOffice.

Install **AbiWord** with Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

Or with the Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install abiword
```

With abiword you can easily open pdf files and then edit them.

Note: First try using LibreOffice. Then KWord. If none works then go for AbiWord.